# Bone snapping to control bone while making an Inverse Kinematic Rig

Tags: rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

Good evening. I have made a humanoid rig and wish to add an IK Controller to the bone "UpperArm.R". I wish to make the bone "CTRL_1.R" bone as a controller bone. Whenever I do so, the control bone snaps to the bone "UpperArm.R". A blend file has been provided. Please look into this. Thank you.

Blend File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RswoL_7QxSEs98YIJ_Ud3OiYzzdGmSnu/view?usp=sharing
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has a very simple answer. When ever you add IK control to a rig, the  default chain length is usually $0$ and the bone tries to point at the rig's origin, thus creating some weird posture.

You can solve this by adjusting the chain length to the number of bone you would like to be influenced by the inverse kinematics(IK).

Try $1$ or $2$ and get a feel of what work best for the rig.

Comment: Unfortuantely thats not the issue. I tried adjusting the chain length to 3 ( that is, 1,2,3) but still the UpperArm bone snaps to the controller bone... Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ever figure this out @BeardedOwl?

Answer (score 0):

You have a dependency loop.  Your IK target, CTRL_1.R, is parented to the IK constrained bone, UpperArm.R.  The position of CTRL depends on UpperArm via parenting, which depends on CTRL via IK, which depends on UpperArm via parenting, forever and ever.  Unparent CTRL.